# Spring data JPA locking

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I need to use @Lock inside of my implementations:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
private Note findOneForUpdate(BigInteger id) {
    return noteDao.findOne(id);
}
```

But other sources say it should be in interfaces:

```
@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, BigInteger>, NoteDao {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Note findOne(BigInteger id);
}
```

So, is first option possible? I tried it with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.3.RELEASE, but lock did not work.

Comment: `@Lock` on anything other then a Spring Data JPA repository doesn't do anything. This annotation is read by Spring Data JPA and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

@Lock annotation is required in repository class

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // not required
private Note findOneForUpdate(BigInteger id) {
    return noteDao.findOne(id);
}

@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, BigInteger>, NoteDao {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // required
    Note findOne(BigInteger id);
}
```